# Storing Object one by one in an xml and reading them as an ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am a newbie to xml-object conversion. I am currently using xstream.

My question is is there any way I can store objects in an xml one by one as in append at the end and while reading read them as an array list.

Basically I have an xml file as

```
<person>
    <firstname>Joe</firstname>
    <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
    <phone>
        <code>123</code>
        <number>1234-456</number>
    </phone>
    <fax>
        <code>123</code>
        <number>9999-999</number>
    </fax>
</person>
<person>
    <firstname>Joe</firstname>
    <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
    <phone>
        <code>123</code>
        <number>1234-456</number>
    </phone>
    <fax>
        <code>123</code>
        <number>9999-999</number>
    </fax>
</person>
```

and I want to be aable to do

```
List<Person> persons = (ArrayLIst<Person()>)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

Is xstream the right thing to use here, is there anything better I can use to achieve this. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Java has JAXB, look into that.

Comment: @nvy As suggested about go to this link. JAXB is easy to understand : http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_3-Hello-World.html#Hello%20World

Comment: The XML fragment in your post isn't valid as there should be one root element.  Is this really your document or is there a root element?

Answer (score 0):

Writing individual objects and reading a list will not work. To see why, write a few objects using `toXml` in one file and write a `List` of the objects in another and compare the two.

However, it should be fairly easy to read individual objects one by one and add it to the list, something on the lines of

```
create list
while (read object using fromXml)
  add to list
```

Comment: I am still a little confused about the approach you mentioned ... Do you mean this 

`List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();`<br/>
`Person person;`<br/>
`while(person = (Person)xstream.fromXML(xml)){`<br/>
`    add person to list`<br/>
`}`

Comment: No I meant you read one `Person` at a time and add it to list. Something on the lines of `while(Person p = (Person)xstream.fromXML(reader) { persons.add(p); }` but you will have to try it out.

Comment: I am getting Xstream InitializationError LOL, I am fighting with that right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting it the first time you call fromXml?

Comment: Yes I do get it the first I when I instantiate my xstream object.....right here XStream xstream = new XStream();

Comment: Also I do test driven development so I created a method as you suggested and ran a Junit, can that be a problem, its my first time using xstream so not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I found out what was wrong with the error I just needed a new version of jar ..... but I dont think I would be able to do the thing we discussed ... it says xml is not well formed, since I dont have a wrapping root element I guess .... do you think we can get around that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Java [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [XMLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) classes. They are as easy to use as object input and output streams and can write any objects with getters and setters for properties that should be preseved, also collections and also more than one object to the same stream. The drawback is that XML they generate and read is rather difficult to understand for humans.

If you write objects manually one by one, you also need to read them one by one until get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (an interesting event to detect EOF but this is how it is documented). You cannot load the whole collection in a single call but a trivial loop seems nothing complex here and you get your ArrayList at the end.

Comment: Downvoter, what do you think is wrong with this approach? Is it just "not cool" to use standard libraries or seems too easy for you?

Comment: I am not sure who downvoted your answer, but I did not downvote your answer @Audrius Meškauskas. +1 for your effort!

Comment: Does it address OP's problem of writing one object at a time and reading into a collection?